# how come answers and questions are banned without feedback

Tags: discussion, community

how come answers and questions are banned without feedback and essential system issues cannot be resolved and re propose again and again (?) Is this question unproperly phrased (?)

Comment: The question seems unproperly phrased to me: I cannot tell what kind of problem you are having. Use your vocabulary. Use grammar and punctuation that others will recognize. Try be factual; describe clearly, avoid complaining. Try to ask a single, clear question that is also answerable by the community. It's on you to communicate the problem effectively to those of us who were not there.

Comment: On looking at your history on AU I can see that 3 of your answers have been deleted without any information added as to why this occurred. The deletions were by a combination of elected and community moderators. In all 3 cases the answers were rightfully removed, IMHO, but I believe a shortcoming in these cases  is that *there was no explanation appended*. And in this Ask Ubuntu should often do better...

Comment: Surely, the question is general and not specific. Surely, banning 3 answers, and on one i would probably agree, without providing a reason is less than efficient and productive for the community. If I recall correctly I also earned a badge for another answer. This means the system has partial and unweighted records on which to decide. Alas, at least it seems it was not phrased so badly this time round. Thnx for feedback

Answer (score 6):

I think it's entirely fair that you get some feedback, and that should really be handled at the point that your posts are being moderated. I think sometimes people think that an action is so very obvious that they don't need to say anything about it. I'm sorry people haven't been more forthcoming.

Some of your Answers haven't met the base requirements for answers. Some haven't answered the question (eg, you've just said you've had the same problem), and a couple didn't really make much sense to me, which may be a rushed post, or a language barrier.

Really for a site like this to survive, answers have to answer the question in a clear way. There isn't room in the answer section for chaff. That might seem unfair but it's the cost of doing business here.

I'm not sure why you've only just been answer-banned. Your last flagged answer was a while ago.
You are not banned from asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

There are no specifics in your question so we can only give you general information.

There are several help page topics that go into reasons why questions and answers would be closed or deleted:

- [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://askubuntu.com/help/closed-questions)
- [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-questions)
- [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers)
- [Why are answers no longer being accepted from my account?](https://askubuntu.com/help/answer-bans)

Please remember that Ask Ubuntu is community moderated. Sometimes questions or answers are removed that shouldn't have been removed. This is often due to a misunderstanding, so it's really important that you make a good effort to ensure that your question or answer is clear and specific and on-topic.

If you believe that a specific question or answer was removed and shouldn't have been, you should post a question about it here on Meta. Tell us why you think it shouldn't be closed and we can have a discussion about it.  Either we will agree with you and reopen it, or we can tell you exactly why it was removed.

Just like on the main site, if you ask a vague question, you can only get a vague answer. But hopefully this gives you enough information to understand why your questions or answers were deleted.

Comment: You could add to that list: [How do I write a good answer?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) @fred While I agree that an explanation should often be given, you also have some responsibility yourself to read up on how the site works - especially when your answers are moderated. A good place to start is reading the link above, which would most likely shed some light on as to why an answer isn't considered "good enough".